# Python Django models distance between coordinates

Tags: python, django

I have 2 `django models` with different places types and their coordinates on a map. I want to get all objects from `first model` and then for each of them get places from `second model` that are within certain range around them. I thought about making a model function like:

```
from haversine import haversine, Unit
def checkRange(self, coords, desired_distance):
    distance = haversine(self.coords, coords)
    if distance < desired_distance:
        return self
```

But i figured that would be a big perfomance problem if i check all of them against each other. What would be an optimal method for that?

Comment: Are you using Postgres and GeoDjango?

Comment: I can use postgres, right now its on default sqlite. I would prefer to avoid custom models like geoDjango if possible.

Comment: GeoDjango is included in Django, it would definitely be your best option as you can perform efficient spatial/distance queries in a DB query

Comment: I didn't knew it was included in Django, interesting... Could you please show me some sort of a similar code sample?

Comment: The official docs for distance queries is probably the best source of information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries

Comment: Ok, one last question. Why should it be postgres, or its gonna work with sqlite aswell? (since its a test local project).

Comment: Sqlite does not support distance queries. I highly recommend PostgreSQL as Django has a lot of support for PostgreSQL specific functionality, it's also just a really good open source database